# npm not working - "read ECONNRESET"

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm having a problem with npm, I cant install anything. Here is the error messages:

```
C:\Windows\system32>npm install -g yo
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/yo
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/yo
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/yo
npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settin
gs.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "yo"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Windows\system32
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.17
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.8
npm ERR! syscall read
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Windows\system32\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Any idea why is this? Here are my network settings and it seems I dont have any proxy configured. I also disabled all the firewalls.

[image]

Comment: Are you able to visit this page in a browser https://registry.npmjs.org/yo?

Comment: It appears their SSL certificate expired!

Comment: @thefourtheye Yes I can visit that link

Comment: npm doesnt install anything. This problem isnt exclusive in installing express

Comment: You may need to check C:\Windows\system32\npm-debug.log, this file will have more accurate information to resolve your problem.

Answer (score 452, accepted):

use

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

so that npm requests for `http` url instead of `https`.

and then try the same `npm install` command

Comment: can you please also provide some explanation , it will be very helpful.

Comment: This "fix" is susceptible to man-in-the-middle attacks.  I wouldn't use this for production.

Comment: The problem could easily be you are being blocked to that website by your ISP's or Company's firewall/proxy.  Using the above method is quicker and easier but it's also insecure as it doesnt verify you are connected to the right website.  To check if you are being blocked simply go to https://registry.npmjs.org/ in your browser.  You should get some text back.

Comment: haha....I'd been trying to get past this off and on for months. I had been just disabling VPN, grabbing packages, then logging back on. Thanks for this. All others, issue is simply your proxy address/port is wrong or (in this case) your proxy is not configured to listen for HTTPS traffic.

Comment: I know it may not be secure but come on - I TRIED EVERYTHING to get rid of ECONNRESET error while creating new angular 4 app via Angular CLI and that solution only worked. After creating new project you can switch back to https. Anyway @mithunsatheesh thank you once again.

Comment: Right now configuring npm to use http instead of https doesn't resolve the econnect error. Instead, it results in a different error:

npm ERR! code ENOAUDIT
npm ERR! audit Your configured registry (http://registry.npmjs.org/) may not support audit requests, or the audit endpoint may be temporarily unavailable.

Comment: @Mithun Satheesh getting SocketException: OS Error: Connection timed out, errno = 110, address = 10.xxx.xx.xxx, port = 43xxx , with local host api, any solution i tried all these command of npm.

Answer (score 85):

You may want to check your NPM proxy settings and perhaps remove it.

```
npm config get proxy
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
```

One might expect a fresh install of NodeJS+NPM would not have a proxy configured. Strangely enough, mine did come with a proxy defined, pointing to an IP and port 3128. Removing the proxy did the trick.

Comment: I was trying to install jquery in Angular project using the cmd - npm install jquery
But there was a proxy error which is now resolved when tried this solution.

Comment: After a day, I have solved my problem **npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings** with this solution. Thanks

Comment: This actually worked, and it seems to be more secure than the other solution.

Comment: This worked for me also. Unfortunately the earlier solution not worked.

Answer (score 21):

Remove your proxy settings at home and switch on at Office networks, This may be irritating, But It worked for me:

```
npm config set proxy http://xxx.xxx.xxx.4:8080   
npm config set https-proxy http://xxx.xxx.xxx.4:8080
```

and

```
npm config rm proxy   
npm config rm https-proxy
```

Comment: The last bit worked for me - I checked my .npmrc file and the old https proxy was still there after removing the proxy

Comment: this is working but how to unconfigure or reconfigure to default, whenever go to other network with out proxy??

Answer (score 18):

You may also need to specify the proxy server/port, in some environments the system settings for proxy are not enough for npm to work.

```
    npm config set proxy "http://your-proxy.com:80"
```

Answer (score 14):

This can be caused by installing anything with npm using `sudo` -- this causes the files in the cache to be owned by root, resulting in this problem. You can fix it by running:

`sudo rm -rf ~/.npm`

to remove the cache. Then try whatever you were doing again, making sure you never use `sudo` along with `npm` (or the problem may come back).

Lots more information: [npm throws error without sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo/24404451#24404451)

Comment: forgot about needing to elevate to Administrator to perform `npm -g update` (as I did to install it). Thanks.

Comment: How does this cause `ECONNRESET`, exactly? You're right that `sudo` can break things in novel ways, but causing the registry server to drop connection is a bit unbelievable.

Comment: This worked for me! I was trying to do `npm i next-pwa` and got similar error as mentioned in the question. Didn't have a proxy set so other solutions didn't work for me. I remembered having used `sudo` and `npm` commands together previously so tried this solution and hopefully it worked as well. Loads of thanks @Kevin!

Answer (score 9):

Restarting my PC made it worked.

Comment: So true, tried all the other solutions, this worked. But in my case, I also ran the `sudo apt update` -> `sudo apt upgrade` before deleting my node_modules folder and tried installing again only to encounter this error. Restart fixed it for me.

Comment: Solution that legends doo

Answer (score 8):

Remove `yarn.lock` , `package-lock.json`, `node_modules`

and then

```
npm install -f
```

Worked for me

Answer (score 4):

The three thing to make npm working well inside the proxy network .

This set npm registry , By default it may take https.

> npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org/"

Second is two set proxy in your system . If your organization use proxy or you.

> npm config set proxy "http://username:password@proxy-url:proxy-port"
>
> npm config set https-proxy
>   "http://username:password@proxy-url:proxy-port"

You can also check if they are set or not , by

> npm config get https-proxy

for all values.

Comment: It does not show me any error, but installation is stuck at line -  loadRequestedDeps: sill install loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree

Comment: This is another issue . The proxy issue of your is solved . May this short your thing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40874237/npm-install-hangs-on-loadrequesteddeps

Answer (score 4):

`npm config rm proxy`

`npm config rm https-proxy`

works for me!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue in windows while installing any package from npm. Fixed that with -
** open command prompt as administrator and run these 3 commands **/

**1.** npm config rm proxy

**2.** npm config rm https-proxy

**3.**  npm install npm@latest -g

**FOR MAC / LINUX**
**1.** sudo npm config rm proxy

**2.** sudo npm config rm https-proxy

**3.** sudo npm install npm@latest -g

Basically this was version isuue with npm . Please check its worrking

Answer (score 4):

I've tried almost all methods posted here and in other pages but didn't work. Here are the commands I've executed in order, which I encourage you to try because it worked for many people (but not me):

- `npm config rm proxy`
- `npm config rm https-proxy`
- `npm config set https-proxy https://username:password@proxy.company.com:6050`
- `npm config set proxy http://username:password@proxy.company.com:6050`
- `npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/`

And then trying to install the package `npm install -g express`, but it failed.

However, when I tried to run `npm install npm@latest -g` it *miraculously* executed and installed fine!
Then running `npm install -g express` again worked perfectly fine too.

**TL;DR**: updating npm to the latest version solved the issue (currently 6.0.1)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue but none of these solutions worked correctly. Finally, I have installed packages via [**yarn**](https://yarnpkg.com/), which is npm-compatible. As per official website:

> Migrating from npm should be a fairly easy process for most users.
> Yarn can consume the same package.json format as npm, and can install
> any package from the npm registry.

Just install the yarn and then then, run the install by using the following command, the equivalent to `npm install` in yarn:

```
yarn install
```

Read more at – [Yarn: Migrating from npm](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/migrating-from-npm/).

Comment: yarn is managing issues with the network - retrying, instead of aborting like npm

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but anyway.

I had this issue, when I was trying to deploy to heroku, and the fix that worked for me was to update the `npm` version that was used. I had version 2.x.x and I updated to 3.x.x

Comment: Or specify an npm version compatible with the node engine being used.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Windows you should follow up on Advanced System Settings to check the env vars declared over there, you should notice that the proxy configuration may lie within environment variables, like in the picture below:

[image: Windows env vars]

So if your proxy server is not available or is blocking traffic from npm you might notice the aforementioned error in this topic. Maybe you don't need any proxy at all, in this case, just remove this HTTP_PROXY env variables.

I had turned all proxy configurations off in my Windows and npm settings, however, npm was still getting timeout and connection errors while downloading resources, then I figured out there was still a proxy configuration left on env variables, which was causing all the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

At work, i had to load up my browser and browse a webpage (which authenticates me to our web-filter).  Then I retried the command and it worked successfully.

Comment: Not 100% sure if this is what helped me, or just a coincidence, but navigating to https://registry.npmjs.org/ in Firefox somehow helped npm install work the next time. I don't have any kind of web filter software.

Answer (score 1):

You may also encounter this error if you have a saved bearer token that is now invalid. I've encountered this when using a private repo where the accounts were wiped and reset, invalidating the tokens. Although your repo may not require authentication, if you have a token from a previous login it will be passed and if it's invalid your connection will be closed.

You can resolve this by either logging in again with the new user name and password, or presumably by simply logging out via npm.

Answer (score 1):

I did not want to switch to http for the registry, what worked for me was downgrading from the latest Node version to the LTS version (as of now, 6.x).

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem with npm throwing this error.

So basically whenever error was thrown i either used manual install
from git or waited and installed specified version like:

```
npm install resolve@^1.1.6
```

when running alone:

```
npm install resolve
```

didn't worked.

<strike>I updated node.js from 7 to 8 and npm install goes smoothly.</strike>

I think that maybe the version 7 caused this problem since [@luschn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43049611/7096189) downgraded to 6 so he didn't use 7 too.

Maybe the registry itself is returning errors without showing problems on their status pages because after some time i could install this one breaking package and then proceed with `npm install` to install the rest.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my local home network without proxy. Other answers in this thread didn't work for me. What I ended up doing was using `yarn` which can be used interchangeably with `npm`:

```
yarn add
```

To this day I don't know why my npm still don't work. I know for sure that it's a problem with my Wi-Fi, because when I connect to LTE internet broadcasted from my smartphone `npm install` works again. It has probably something to do with router settings (problems started when I upgraded my internet speed and ISP worker replaced my old router with a new one).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when trying to run `npm` on system emulated in **Oracle VirtualBox**. I resolved it by adding Google DNS address in Network Adapter properties.

Network Adapter properties > IPv4 properties > Preferred DNS address: `8.8.8.8`.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me:

```
proxy = http://1.1.1.1:3128/
https_proxy = http://1.1.1.1:3128/
strict-ssl = false
ca = null
registry = http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Answer found here: https://fak3r.com/2015/07/31/howto-use-npm-behind-a-corporate-proxy/

Answer (score 1):

Our company firewall will stop installing node hence connect to the personal network and install, it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I found "npm config edit" to be more useful to update the entries for https-proxy, proxy, registry

I did something like this

- npm config list
- npm config edit (opens in vi)
- Edit or set the config entries for https-proxy, proxy, registry
- npm install

Answer (score 1):

Just in case...simply trying one more time worked for me. It **could** just be a temporary connection issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple solution for this. if you are using windows 10 then go to the network setting and turn off the automatic proxy detection.it solved my problem. I was looking for this for the last 2 days.

Answer (score 1):

In my case changing wifi works for me. I usually work in my living room. But I changed to my room just a few days ago. The wifi did not reach the 2nd floor so we used **Wifi Extender**.

Then I had this issue. I tried switching back to my living room's wifi and I got no problem from doing the same command.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this - same problem and same solution!!

Comment: Haha glad it helped @RichardFoss apparently it's a network issue as the error implied I guess `ECONNRESET`, connection reset stuff.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was running a Node JS application in another CMD, and that application was listening to port `8088`.

So when I was executing any command related to npm it was throwing the above error.

**The solution in my case was**: Stopping ANY Running Node JS applications and retrying to execute the npm command again. the installation should be completed successfully, without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

npm config set https-proxy "http://username:password@proxy-url:proxy-port" worked for me

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anyone who was in my situation: I recently installed Fiddler, which (unbeknownst to me) added a network proxy through `127.0.0.1:8866`. I went into my Ubuntu network settings, clicked into the "Network Proxy" settings, and disabled it, and then all was back to normal.

So in general, check to make sure you haven't got a network proxy set up due to a side-effect of something else you were doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you live in China, try the below command, it's the npm mirror registry, and supports https:

`npm config set registry https://registry.npmmirror.com/`

Answer (score 0):

use

> npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/

then try the same npm install command

Answer (score -1):

it solved for me by use this code :
npm install -g yarn

yarn global add create-react-app

Answer (score -1):

May be node version demand from the code is not up to mark, Try "npm install" , you can see what version the code demand

Answer (score -1):

This issue often arises due to internet connectivity problems or slow internet speeds. Initially, I encountered this issue as well, but after trying a few times, I managed to resolve it.

**Check Your Internet Connection:** Ensure that your internet connection is stable and working properly. Sometimes intermittent connectivity issues can cause ECONNRESET errors.

Answer (score -1):

adding the -d flag worked for me

```
npm -d i
```

Answer (score -4):

## Solution 1:

#### MAC + LINUX

run this command with `sudo`

```
sudo npm install -g yo
```

#### Windows

run cmd as `administrator` and then run this command again

## Solution 2:

run this command and then try

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```