# Can't install anything with npm ECONNRESET without proxy

Tags: node.js, cordova, proxy, npm, ionic-framework

I used node.js to install some things via npm without any problems. Now I changed nothing on my settings (Win8; no proxy, internet is working) and I can't install anything (especially cordova and ionic).
It only throws errors like I'm behind a proxy, but I'm not.

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "i" "-g" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v0.12.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read

npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\Web\dierechnungstimmt\npm-debug.log
```

and

```
    npm WARN engine cordova-js@3.8.0: wanted: {"node":"~0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.1","npm":"2.5.1"})
npm WARN engine npm@1.3.4: wanted: {"node":">=0.6","npm":"1"} (current: {"node":"0.12.1","npm":"2.5.1"})
npm WARN engine xmlbuilder@2.2.1: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x || 0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.1","npm":"2.5.1"})
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/stack-trace/-/stack-trace-0.0.9.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/is-utf8/-/is-utf8-0.2.0.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/gaze/-/gaze-0.5.1.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/core-util-is/-/core-util-is-1.0.1.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/strip-ansi/-/strip-ansi-0.3.0.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/stream-consume/-/stream-consume-0.1.0.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash._reescape/-/lodash._reescape-3.0.0.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/through2/-/through2-0.6.3.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/inflight/-/inflight-1.0.4.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-regex/-/ansi-regex-0.2.1.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash._basecopy/-/lodash._basecopy-3.0.0.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/clone/-/clone-0.2.0.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/readable-stream/-/readable-stream-1.1.13.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch/-/minimatch-0.2.14.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/readable-stream/-/readable-stream-1.1.13.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: read ECONNRESET
C:\Users\Basti\AppData\Roaming\npm\cordova -> C:\Users\Basti\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\bin\cordova
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/core-util-is/-/core-util-is-1.0.1.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: read ECONNRESET
C:\Users\Basti\AppData\Roaming\npm\ionic -> C:\Users\Basti\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\bin\ionic
i@0.3.2 C:\Users\Basti\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\i

cordova@4.3.0 C:\Users\Basti\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova
Ôö£ÔöÇÔöÇ underscore@1.7.0
Ôö£ÔöÇÔöÇ q@1.0.1
Ôö£ÔöÇÔöÇ nopt@3.0.1 (abbrev@1.0.5)
ÔööÔöÇÔöÇ cordova-lib@4.3.0 (valid-identifier@0.0.1, osenv@0.1.0, properties-parser@0.2.3, bplist-parser@0.0.6, mime@1.2.11, semver@2.0.11, unorm@1.3.3, shelljs@0.3.0, dep-graph@1.1.0, d8@0.4.4, rc@0.5.2, through2@0.6.3, npmconf@0.1.16, glob@4.0.6, xcode@0.6.7, init-package-json@1.3.0, elementtree@0.1.5, request@2.47.0, tar@1.0.2, plist@1.1.0, npm@1.3.4, cordova-js@3.8.0)

ionic@1.3.18 C:\Users\Basti\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic
Ôö£ÔöÇÔöÇ proxy-middleware@0.7.0
Ôö£ÔöÇÔöÇ connect-livereload@0.5.2
Ôö£ÔöÇÔöÇ progress@1.1.7
Ôö£ÔöÇÔöÇ colors@0.6.2
Ôö£ÔöÇÔöÇ open@0.0.5
Ôö£ÔöÇÔöÇ underscore@1.7.0
Ôö£ÔöÇÔöÇ ncp@0.4.2
Ôö£ÔöÇÔöÇ crc@3.2.1
Ôö£ÔöÇÔöÇ async@0.9.0
Ôö£ÔöÇÔöÇ q@1.0.1
Ôö£ÔöÇÔöÇ semver@4.3.1
Ôö£ÔöÇÔöÇ shelljs@0.2.6
Ôö£ÔöÇÔöÇ cross-spawn@0.2.3 (lru-cache@2.5.0)
Ôö£ÔöÇÔöÇ event-stream@3.0.20 (stream-combiner@0.0.4, duplexer@0.1.1, from@0.1.3, pause-stream@0.0.11, map-stream@0.0.5, split@0.2.10, through@2.3.6)
Ôö£ÔöÇÔöÇ optimist@0.6.0 (wordwrap@0.0.2, minimist@0.0.10)
Ôö£ÔöÇÔöÇ opbeat-ionic@1.1.3 (json-stringify-safe@5.0.0, console-log-level@1.0.0, stackman@0.2.2, after-all@2.0.1)
Ôö£ÔöÇÔöÇ form-data@0.1.4 (mime@1.2.11, combined-stream@0.0.7)
Ôö£ÔöÇÔöÇ finalhandler@0.2.0 (escape-html@1.0.1, debug@2.0.0)
Ôö£ÔöÇÔöÇ connect@3.1.1 (utils-merge@1.0.0, parseurl@1.3.0, debug@1.0.4, finalhandler@0.1.0)
Ôö£ÔöÇÔöÇ serve-static@1.7.1 (utils-merge@1.0.0, escape-html@1.0.1, parseurl@1.3.0, send@0.10.1)
Ôö£ÔöÇÔöÇ tiny-lr-fork@0.0.5 (debug@0.7.4, faye-websocket@0.4.4, qs@0.5.6, noptify@0.0.3)
Ôö£ÔöÇÔöÇ xml2js@0.4.4 (sax@0.6.1, xmlbuilder@2.6.2)
Ôö£ÔöÇÔöÇ unzip@0.1.9 (setimmediate@1.0.2, pullstream@0.4.1, match-stream@0.0.2, readable-stream@1.0.33, binary@0.3.0, fstream@0.1.31)
Ôö£ÔöÇÔöÇ request@2.51.0 (caseless@0.8.0, json-stringify-safe@5.0.0, aws-sign2@0.5.0, forever-agent@0.5.2, stringstream@0.0.4, oauth-sign@0.5.0, tunnel-agent@0.4.0, node-uuid@1.4.3, qs@2.3.3, mime-types@1.0.2, combined-stream@0.0.7, tough-cookie@0.12.1, http-signature@0.10.1, form-data@0.2.0, hawk@1.1.1, bl@0.9.4)
Ôö£ÔöÇÔöÇ npm@2.1.3
Ôö£ÔöÇÔöÇ prompt@0.2.12 (revalidator@0.1.8, pkginfo@0.3.0, read@1.0.5, utile@0.2.1, winston@0.6.2)
Ôö£ÔöÇÔöÇ archiver@0.5.1 (lodash@2.4.1, readable-stream@1.1.13, lazystream@0.1.0, zip-stream@0.1.4, file-utils@0.1.5)
Ôö£ÔöÇÔöÇ vinyl-fs@0.3.7 (graceful-fs@3.0.6, lodash@2.4.1, vinyl@0.4.6, mkdirp@0.5.0, strip-bom@1.0.0, through2@0.6.3, glob-stream@3.1.18, glob-watcher@0.0.6)
ÔööÔöÇÔöÇ gulp@3.8.8 (pretty-hrtime@0.2.2, interpret@0.3.10, deprecated@0.0.1, archy@0.0.2, minimist@1.1.1, semver@3.0.1, tildify@1.0.0, orchestrator@0.3.7, liftoff@0.12.1, chalk@0.5.1, gulp-util@3.0.4)
```

Can anyone please help me?

EDIT:
Tried to downgrade to node 0.10 an run cmd as administrator, but it still doesn't work:

```
C:\Users\Basti\Desktop>npm install i -g cordova
npm WARN engine npm@1.3.4: wanted: {"node":">=0.6","npm":"1"} (current: {"node":"0.10.38","npm":"2.7.4"})
npm WARN installMany normalize-package-data was bundled with npm@1.3.4, but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree
C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\cordova -> C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\cordova\bin\cordova
i@0.3.2 C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\i

cordova@4.3.0 C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\cordova
Ôö£ÔöÇÔöÇ underscore@1.7.0
Ôö£ÔöÇÔöÇ q@1.0.1
Ôö£ÔöÇÔöÇ nopt@3.0.1 (abbrev@1.0.5)
ÔööÔöÇÔöÇ cordova-lib@4.3.0 (valid-identifier@0.0.1, osenv@0.1.0, properties-parser@0.2.3, bplist-parser@0.0.6, mime@1.2.11, semver@2.0.11, unorm@1.3.3, rc@0.5.2, shelljs@0.3.0, dep-graph@1.1.0, npmconf@0.1.16, through2@0.6.3, xcode@0.6.7, init-package-json@1.3.0, d8@0.4.4, elementtree@0.1.5, request@2.47.0, glob@4.0.6, tar@1.0.2, plist@1.1.0, cordova-js@3.8.0, npm@1.3.4)
```

Comment: try opening the command line as adminstrator? does that make a diffarence?

Comment: try with `powershell`, its success with me

Comment: possible duplicate of [npm not working - "read ECONNRESET"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419144/npm-not-working-read-econnreset)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71263193/7056207 try this, it may help

Answer (score 47):

Well, actually, I want to give a comment to your question. Because I have low reputation, it means I can't give a.

If you have a trouble with `npm` on Windows. I would suggest you take a look the common errors of `npm` on wiki [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/troubleshooting/common-errors). Back to your problem, please make sure you are using internet connection along with proxy or not. If you are using it, please do command `npm config set proxy`. I found same problem on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419144/npm-not-working-read-econnreset) and the solution is:

> use
>
> `npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/`
>
> so that npm requests for `http` url instead of `https`.
>
> and then try the same `npm install` command.

Don't forget to clear your cache by doing `npm cache clean`.

Although, this way can solve the problem. You should consider about the security. This way is **not the safe way** because it can lead to security problem since `https` is not used here. I don't recommend to use this on production (thanks @ivarni for pointing this out).

Comment: Thanks, man! I've had to downgrade from my Mint box to this piece of s**t windows 8 and I've been a week at trying to build my dev env. This totally got rid of the network errors.

Comment: Thanks. +1 This helped me too.

Comment: Installing npm modules without SSL is a pretty bad idea. If someone intercepts the request they can return pretty much anything and a malicious node module can run arbitrary code in its `postinstall` task as the current user.

Comment: You're right @ivarni. This way is not safe. I don't recommend using this on production.

Answer (score 5):

**The following worked for me**

1. Instead of using cmd, use the "Node.js commandprompt". To do this, type node in start menu, and on the results, click on "Node.js commandprompt". This will setup the required env variables
2. In the above shell, run the command

> npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/

3. Run the command

> npm install -g cordova

4. Run the command

> npm install -g ionic

Answer (score 2):

I was got a similar issue.

I was run below commands

npm config edit

Open that file and remove line no approx 8 
    proxy=http://github.com/
    registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/
 those are user custom settings remove this file and save it.

After run  below command 
npm install should be work fine.

Comment: I don't know why but my config had a proxy to my local machiine (127.0.0.1) for some reason. Removing it fixed the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Had the similar issue on Windows 10 with Node v5.0.0

Another solution from [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8196) that works for me:

Try to unistall x64 version of Node.js and install x86 one.

Answer (score 0):

The best discussion of the `ECONNRESET` issue is in this npm registry ticket:
https://github.com/npm/registry-issue-archive/issues/10

tl;dr: If you are seeing this frequently, it may be a "too many simultaneous connections" issue that can be addressed by updating your version of npm to `2.15.x` or `3.x / latest`.

One comment (no rep to comment directly) on posts by Shokatsuryō-san & Sunil: both recommend changing your npm registry config to use http over https. Doing so can present a significant security risk in production environments; don't use that fix in those cases.

Answer (score 0):

I actually had the same problem, from my workplace I could install everything fine, but it wasn't working from home.
I found out that the custom DNS I set up on my routeur was the problem, I have reverted to the default internet provider one and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while installing the expo-cli in Windows 8.1, but it resolved after i have followed the below steps.

run below command in your command prompt.

```
npm config edit
```

.npmrc file will open in your default editor.

Now remove the lines having proxy, https-proxy, registery and save that file.

After that i was able to install the expo-cli package without the proxy issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in corpnet with a proxy and none of the provided solutions worked for you, most probably you`ll need to provide your proxy with your credentials, something like this:

> npm config set proxy http://username:password@host:port

> npm config set https-proxy http://username:password@host:port

This took a lot of time from me today, hopefully this post will save some of yours.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with jdbc package installation. I was also behind a proxy. I used a force install and it worked.

> npm i jdbc --force

Note: Make sure you know the consequences of --force install by checking the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

That is work for me:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

After clear your cache, run this command :

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

And `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

guys I just came across this problem and solved it by:

```
npm config edit
```

then clear out you're .npmrc file,

save it afterwards just try out creating your react-app,

happy-hacking!

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked by turning off Windows Defender and then running the following commands (run CMD as an admin).

First, take note of the config default values via `npm config ls -l`.

Next:

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

I have slow internet connection so these are needed:

```
npm fetch-retry-maxtimeout 360000
npm fetch-retry-mintimeout 60000
```

Clean cache:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Once that is done, I ran `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`. then reverted all my configs to the default values.

Don't forget to turn back Windows Defender on.