# Win 10 nodejs (6.6) with npm (3.10.3) can't install cordova

Tags: node.js, windows, cordova, networking, installation

I installed nodejs 6.6 and wanted to install Cordova.
So in the command line I typed:

```
npm install -g Cordova
```

If failed.

I search the web and found to do the followings:

```
npm config set proxy http://user:password@url:port
npm config set https-proxy http://user:password@url:port
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

I tried again it still failed; so I search again [Can't install anything with npm ECONNRESET without proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29395793/cant-install-anything-with-npm-econnreset-without-proxy)

And executed the followings:

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
npm cache clean
```

Still the installed failed.
It's on a private computer from a home connexion.
My last attempt:

```
C:\Users\An>npm config set proxy

C:\Users\An>npm cache clean
npm WARN invalid config proxy=""
npm WARN invalid config Must be a full url with 'http://'
npm WARN invalid config proxy=""
npm WARN invalid config Must be a full url with 'http://'

C:\Users\An>npm install -g Cordova
npm WARN invalid config proxy=""
npm WARN invalid config Must be a full url with 'http://'
npm WARN invalid config proxy=""
npm WARN invalid config Must be a full url with 'http://'
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "Cordova"
npm ERR! node v6.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 Registry returned 404 for GET on http://registry.npmjs.org/Cordova
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'Cordova' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 Your package name is not valid, because
npm ERR! 404  1. name can no longer contain capital letters
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\An\npm-debug.log

C:\Users\An>
```

And

```
    C:\Users\An>npm config set proxy http://user:password@url:port

C:\Users\An>npm config set https-proxy http://user:password@url:port

C:\Users\An>npm config set strict-ssl false

C:\Users\An>npm install -g Cordova
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "Cordova"
npm ERR! node v6.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo

npm ERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND url url:80
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\An\npm-debug.log

C:\Users\An>
```