# JAXB2 Import: Could not process schema files (in28minutes udemy)

Tags: java, maven, eclipse-plugin, pom.xml, jaxb2-maven-plugin

I get a "could not process schema files" error on the `<exception>` line when I try to add the JAXB2 plugin...

**pom.xml**

```
    <plugins>
        <!-- JAXB2 Maven Plugin -->
        <!-- XSD Source Folder -->
        <!-- Java Class Source Folder -->
        <!-- clear folder -> false -->
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>xjc</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
                <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Screenshot of error:

[image]

Comment: well.. what are the files in that directory?

Comment: It's only my application.properties file, which is blank by the way.

Comment: Well if there's no schema files (`.xsd`) in that directory then no wonder

Comment: Um, so... how do I get something there? I've tried Maven Update Project...

Comment: Please check the Maven console in Eclipse. Or run `mvn clean install` from the command line and post the output.

Comment: Updating "node" and "npm" versions also can resolve this. According to current versions,
<configuration>
       <nodeVersion>v16.14.0</nodeVersion>
       <nodeDownloadRoot>http://nodejs.org/dist/</nodeDownloadRoot>
       <npmVersion>8.5.2</npmVersion>
      </configuration>
this helped me resolve issue.

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar problem just make sure xsd file has

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
</xsd:schema>
```

Not

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
</schema>`
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, This issue is resolved by keeping `<plugins></plugins> content inside <pluginManagement>` tag as below,

```
<build>
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins> 
          <plugin>
           ...
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
           ...
          </plugin>
     </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
</build>
```