# windows: npm install getting error ERR! code ECONNRESET

Tags: node.js, npm, ionic-framework

I try to install ionic, but when run `npm install -g ionic` I have error below.

```
npm ERR! node v0.12.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET

npm ERR! network socket hang up
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settin
gs.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

My network don't have proxy, and when i run `npm get proxy` it said `null`

I already try to clean cache, and change registry to `http://registry.npmjs.org/` and `https://registry.npmjs.org/` and also I can access http://registry.npmjs.org/yo, but still have same error when installing ionic.

hope any solution for my issue.

Thank you,

Comment: It worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419144/npm-not-working-read-econnreset

Answer (score 1):

There is some dependency problem.

see below link :

http://ionicframework.com/docs/concepts/development.html

> Improved answer Below :
>   By default, brew install latest stable version of node (in this case 0.12.4). Based on the warning messages, ionic is expecting a lower version of node.
>   I was able to to solve this issue by installing a prior version of node (0.10.38).

```
$ brew remove node
$ rm ~/.node   (might want to rename instead)
$ brew install homebrew/versions/node010 
$ node --version
$ v0.10.38
```

Run npm install -g ionic worked as expected.

Comment: I getting error when install the ionic with node.js, it's not about dependency on ionic.

Comment: I improved my answer. Please check it again.