# Installing Ionic on El Capitan fails with ECONNRESET

Tags: node.js, cordova

I have OSX 10.11.1 and Node 4.1.0 installed.

When running the command:

sudo npm install -g cordova ionic

I see the following error:

> npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
>      npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with nam itself
>      npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
>      npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
>      npm ERR! network
>      npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
>      npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
>      npm ERR! Darwin 15.0.0
>      npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "cordova" "ionic"
>      npm ERR! node v4.2.1
>      npm ERR! nam  v2.14.7
>      npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
>      npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
>      npm ERR! sys call read

This problem occurs despite:
1. No Proxy in the network
2. Installing Node using brew or using the pkg from node site

Any pointers will help.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419144/npm-not-working-read-econnreset

Comment: I've tried everything on that post before I posted, but it didn't help.