# Meteor unable to update package catalog

Tags: meteor

```
> meteor publish
Unable to update package catalog (are you offline?)

If you are using Meteor behind a proxy, set HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY environment variables or see this page for more details:  https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Meteor-behind-a-proxy

DDP disconnected while connection in progress 
This command requires an up-to-date package catalog.  Exiting.


> meteor update
Unable to update package catalog (are you offline?)

If you are using Meteor behind a proxy, set HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY environment variables or see this page for more details:  https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Meteor-behind-a-proxy

This project is already at Meteor 1.2.1, the latest release.


The following top-level dependencies were not updated to the very latest version available:
```

I am online. I don't have a proxy. I've tried both on my phone hotspot and behind my home cable modem.

How can I further diagnose the problem?

Comment: similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419144/npm-not-working-read-econnreset

Comment: I saw [on the meteor forums](https://forums.meteor.com/t/fixed-install-meteor-com-is-down/16358) that `meteor install` was down for awhile today

Comment: Thanks Michael, that must have been it – now working.

Answer (score 3):

Meteor package servers were down. In future, you may be able to diagnose this issue by seeing whether `install.meteor.com` is down.