# nodejs or meteor- how get it working on OVH Cloud VPS

Tags: node.js, meteor, proxy, ovh

I got problem using OVH CLOUD VPS and NodeJS / MeteorJS.
When trying to do meteor update I receive:

```
Unable to update package catalog (are you offline?)

If you are using Meteor behind a proxy, set HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY environment variables or see this page for more details:  https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Meteor-behind-a-proxy
```

When trying do any npm install package I get:

```
npm ERR! Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR!     at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
npm ERR!     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:895:19)
npm ERR!  { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
npm ERR!   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'connect' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

I have been googling for some time and all sollutions with making npm set registry or adding / deleting npm config (set / delete) proxy doesnt bring sollution.

Have any of you solved how to use NPM / METEOR on OVH VPS ?

Comment: Have you  figured out meteor-up with ovh.org? Mine is stuck on "- Setting up Environment" for 20 minutes

Comment: Nope. This is your only hope: ```npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/```
But do not expect miracles..

Answer (score 0):

similar question here:
[npm not working - "read ECONNRESET"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419144/npm-not-working-read-econnreset)

answer I believe is:

`npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/`

or `https`

Comment: I have already checked other q&a on stackoverflow, none of them brought sollution for npm / node on OVH VPS Cloud

Comment: have you tried a simple npm install to see if you can get to the registry?

Comment: ovh may have their own npm registry, so you need to find out what the url is. I would try things like registry.npmjs.ovh.net of something or that sort

Comment: interesting, I will try such combinations then

Comment: tested with few few combinations, no success.
Please consider similar problem is with running meteor apps, after they are launched (no matter what port) they usually stuck on any asynchronous call or http post. Like opening socket is problem. No perfect idea. Mby someone did have similar problems with OVH ?

Comment: Sorry I don't know. this is a OVH specific problem so you may want to post in their help forum or contact customer support through your console.