# Facing issue in setting my first react-native project.

Tags: npm, react-native

npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "--save" "--save-exact" "react-native"
npm ERR! node v4.2.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.6
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET

npm ERR! network tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy proxy:8083
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/i816556/AwesomeProject/npm-debug.log

`npm install --save --save-exact react-native` failed

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have some `npm` related issues. Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419144/npm-not-working-read-econnreset) for more help.