# Installing Ionic for android development gets stuck

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, npm

When I try to run the command `npm install -g cordova ionic`, it gets stuck for hours.

[image]

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: I am actually at home using LAN connection.

Comment: Have you tried this answer from a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40874237/npm-install-hangs-on-loadrequesteddeps

Comment: Thank you! It worked :) 
But why? ... doesn't make any sense.
Also should I revert the changes once it is installed?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below step for proceeding further

- Clean the `npm cache`
- Update `npm and node version`
- reinstalling `npm and node`

I found that changing my Environment Variable TEMP to = C:\tmp worked.
use this tutorial https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/cache

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem .So, somewhere I found the below command which worked for me. `npm install -g ionic cordova`