# Is there a way to solve ECONNRESET error when using npm? I need to restart the machine to fix it

Tags: node.js, npm

After using the computer for a while I cant use npm install anymore. If I restart the computer then all gets back to working.
I am using macOS Mojave 10.14.3 with node v11.12.0 and npm 6.9.0.

Tried the solutions here: [npm not working - "read ECONNRESET"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419144/npm-not-working-read-econnreset) but no success

```
npm i faker
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/faker failed, reason: read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/flaviomelo/.npm/_logs/2019-03-28T12_25_35_242Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always possible that for a few minutes, NPM was down - so try again now just in case.

But in general, I would start by trying to find where the problem lies.

Try this:

```
curl https://registry.npmjs.org/faker
```

That should produce pages and pages of JSON. If it doesn't, then it's possible that your terminal - for whatever reason - cannot access the internet. Comments below this answer have further steps you can try in debugging this.

If it does produce lots of JSON, then there is a problem in your version of NPM / node. As these seem to be the latest, try downgrading each to see if it's a new bug.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So I tried using it and I get "curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to registry.npmjs.org:443". Will keep investigating.

Comment: What happens if you try it in a browser? Also, can you tell us what IP address `ping registry.npmjs.org` is giving you? Sounds like either something on the network is hijacking that call (possibly legitimately, to prevent people accidentally pushing top-secret npm modules up) or your computer doesn't have the necessary SSL root certificates to connect with

Comment: Hello, I didn't try on the browser on that day but today it's showing the JSON like you suggested. The problem was temporary apparently. The **ping registry.npmjs.org** gives me 104.16.25.35.
Thanks for your help. Should this question be marked as resolved or something?

Comment: @FlávioMelo I guess so! Glad it's working again though :)

Answer (score 0):

Today I am facing the same issue, and take me hours tried to fixed this issue, for me, it is the network issue about fetching from official, I switched to another registry like this(I am using pnpm):

```
pnpm config set registry https://registry.npm.taobao.org/
```

works for me, hope this idea could save your time.

Answer (score -1):

you can try these solutions

## Solution 1:

#### MAC + LINUX

run this command with `sudo`

```
sudo npm install -g yo
```

#### Windows

run cmd as `administrator` and then run this command again

## Solution 2:

run this command and then try

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```