# Getting error "read ECONNRESET" while creating a new stenciljs project. How to fix the same?

Tags: stenciljs

I am trying to create a new stenciljs project using command `npm init stencil`. As soon as I choose a set up (whether app or component) and hit 'enter', a read ECONNRESET error is prompted.

I have tried updating the npm but nothing is working.

I expect the command prompt to show me the option where I can enter the project name after choosing a setup for my project but it throws an error, instead.

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: Do you have a proxy set up or are behind one? Maybe have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419144/npm-not-working-read-econnreset.

Answer (score 0):

An `ECONNRESET` in `npm` means that `npm` is unable to connect to an URL where it's looking for dependencies or resources. In most cases, that means that your `npm` is unable to connect to the NPM Registry. But in your case it seems different.

You're trying to create a Stencil app, with `npm init stencil`. [Under the hood](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/init), that That means you're using `npm` to download the [`create-stencil`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-stencil) package and run it to generate the scaffold of your Stencil app.

The first part, getting the `create-stencil` package works well, the problem arrives while running the package. If I am correct, `create-stencil` tries to clone the [`stencil-app-starter`](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil-app-starter) GitHub repository and modify it. So maybe you're behind a corporate or university proxy, blocking GitHub, or another the URLs of the `create-stencil` resources, maybe the connection is rather flacky, maybe GitHub was done at that moment...