# protractor installation through npm

Tags: node.js, npm, protractor

Getting ECONNRESET error while trying to install protrator through npm on windows 10 machine
node JS version - v12.16.1 and npm version 6.13.4

Error details:
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/protractor failed, reason: read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

Cross verified npm configuration to ensure proxy is not set by running npm config get proxy and npm config list commands.
Changed registry to http by executing command config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/

Let me know if any alternative exists or solution to overcome this.

Comment: Can you install other packages?

Comment: @DublinDev, getting same error for all packages.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419144/npm-not-working-read-econnreset

Comment: DublinDev: Was able to resolve issue by removing the environment variable with proxy configured.

Comment: @DublinDev: It got resolved on disabling proxy setting on the system. Thanks