# npm not working - “read ECONNRESET” when installing hdwallet-provider

Tags: npm, truffle

Running:

`npm install @truffle/hdwallet-provider`

gives me `ECONNRESET` after being stuck on `rollbackFailedOptional`.

Already tried the first 2 solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419144/npm-not-working-read-econnreset). Already tried running `npm install` again, this one is working properly.

More info on the packet: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@truffle/hdwallet-provider

Yes, I do have Web3 1.2.11, Node v14.3. I am running the command in a VSCode terminal, I have a stable internet connection.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple terminal reset was not enough.

A clean restart of the laptop fixed it (shut down + power on).
What happened is completely beyond me. Maybe this will help somebody else.