# while I am trying install @angular/cli I have this problem

Tags: angular

```
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/resolve: aborted
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\kawthar\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-04-07T06_51_37_056Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Posible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419144/npm-not-working-read-econnreset

Comment: Are you trying to install dependencies behind a proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Before you are trying to install `@angular/cli` you may run the following command

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

so that npm requests for http url instead of https

and then try to run the following command

```
npm install
```

and finally you can try to run the following command

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```