# error network while installing create-react-app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

i've tried many times when installing create react app but it always error connection, but my internet connection is really stable

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

> npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
> npm ERR! syscall read
> npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
> npm ERR! network Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/@svgr%2fplugin-jsx: read ECONNRESET
> npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
> npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
> npm ERR! network
> npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
> npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: i have no idea, i don't think so

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue this Error occurred because you are using proxy server to connect internet if so stopping using proxy will solve it but if you want to keep up with proxy
follow this
first clear cache

```
npm cache clear --force
```

second:

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

third:

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

last:

```
create-react-app appName
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
npm install -g yarn

yarn global add create-react-app

create-react-app my-app
```

Comment: still not working mate

Comment: Try :  `npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/` For npm to use an `http` request instead of an `https` request and then try the same `npm install` command. Source : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419144/npm-not-working-read-econnreset)