# npm install command doesn't work for me. ECONNRESET

Tags: npm

I am trying to install an NPM package in a project but the installation does not go beyond the buildDeps phase and after a while it gives me the error ECONNRESET. This happens to me with any package I try to install:

[image]

I tried to install Express and Angular and couldn't.

Comment: Same issue has been addressed in this [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419144/npm-not-working-read-econnreset)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm not working - "read ECONNRESET"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419144/npm-not-working-read-econnreset)

Answer (score 1):

Try connecting your device to Internet. NPM is a Package manager which add packages stored in servers and deliver to their users.
If problem still persists, try to install NodeJS again