# I can't install react in vs code by using npx create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, npx

**When I am trying to use npx create-react-app it throws an error.**

PS C:\Users\a\Desktop\React> **npx create-react-app frontend-task**
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://infyartifactory.ad.infosys.com/artifactory/api/npm/npm/create-react-app failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND infyartifactory.ad.infosys.com
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

```
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-03-22T05_04_39_752Z-debug.logPS
```

I have no idea what is going on here. I tried npm cache clean --force but still shows the error.

node version - v16.13.0
npm version - 8.1.0

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have an extra /npm in your registry url?

Comment: Possibly you can share your `npm config`- error suggests there's an issue with a proxy.

Comment: Check you internet connection. This can also happen when you're on a University internet so try using a VPN.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33246717/4722345

Comment: Yea you should first make sure you can access artifactory itself before debugging npm.