# npm error While creating React Native Project

Tags: react-native, npm, npm-install

While I'm creating react native app I am facing some problem:

[image]

I try to create a react-native project but it failed.

Comment: Are you using a proxy or something, as tell the error ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm not working - "read ECONNRESET"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419144/npm-not-working-read-econnreset)

Comment: Have you tried running an `npm install`? It looks like your package installation is acting up.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check the node version with `node --v`
2. Try to init with that version `npx react-native init <ProjectName> --version 0.68.5`
3. Check the documentation to make sure the version is stable
4. Update the package if needed

Answer (score 1):

Remove '@latest' from command.
npx react-native init AwesomeProject