Getting error in installing the nextjs app using npx create-next-app@latest
npm WARN deprecated inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce async requests by a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.
npm WARN deprecated @humanwhocodes/config-array@0.11.14: Use @eslint/config-array instead
npm WARN deprecated rimraf@3.0.2: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated @humanwhocodes/object-schema@2.0.3: Use @eslint/object-schema instead
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network aborted
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\akshay shahi\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-08-15T05_24_41_129Z-debug-0.log

Aborting installation.
npm install has failed.
I have already installed the latest Nodejs.

you can try look into this post. Answered by Mithun Satheesh
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18428563/19961869

This question is similar to: npm not working - "read ECONNRESET". If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
